# Deactivating parent page should not affect the child page in cq5

Tags: aem, publish

While deactivating homepage of the website it's deactivating all the child pages under the homepage. Please suggest is there any way that we can deactivate homepage alone rather entire tree.

Comment: This is not the default behavior if you just deactivate the page, though it doesn't make sense. You then might have corrupt pages on the publish server.

Comment: Thanks. i got the point there is no use of deactivating parent page alone.

Answer (score 1):

The pages are part of a tree.  If you deactivate 1 page (or node...) then it basically writes an empty node in its place.  This replacement node has no children, so it effectively deactivates or deletes the sub-tree.

If you desire to keep the children, you have to replace the parent instead of deactivate it.